# The application could not be installed because the installer file is damaged. Try obtaining a new installer file from the application author

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

We have an old version of our application that was successfully code signed using a Thawte SHA 256  certificate. This certificate expired and we are now using a new one.

[image]

When the user upgrades from the old version of the application to the latest, they encounter this error:
Reinstalling the application gets around the issue but we want a more professional solution.

I used the following shell script to sign it, which seems to run successfully, but am still getting the error

```
if (($# < 1))
then
echo "Usage: $0 version"
exit -1
fi
echo "Fixing file permissions..."
chmod a+x bin-debug/bin/SWC

echo "packaging Air file for mac..."
cd bin-debug

/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Shared/flex_sdk_4.6/bin/adt -package -storetype pkcs12  -keystore ../../../thawte\ certificates/airSigningBackup2018.p12 -storepass myPassword -target air ../SW_Desktop_mac.air DieBook-app.xml DieBook.swf bin/SWCM bin/SWCMLE builddate icons
cd ..

/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Shared/flex_sdk_4.6/bin/adt -migrate -storetype pkcs12 -keystore ../../thawte\ certificates/airSigningBackup2016.p12 -storepass myPassword SW_Desktop_mac.air SW_Desktop_mac_migrated.air

/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Shared/flex_sdk_4.6/bin/adt -package -target native SWD_$1.dmg SW_Desktop_mac_migrated.air

echo "SWD_$1.dmg should be ready now."
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember, this issue happens when you have multiple versions of the same app with same version number installed. I don't remember if its the verison number but i'm sure it's one of the unique identifiers ind the XML. So for each new version change that identifier and all should be well.